# Efficient conversion between Smile and JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I've read that the conversion between Smile and JSON can be done efficiently in a few sources:

- *This means that conversion between JSON and Smile can be done efficiently and without loss of information.* ([github, jackson-docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance));
- *The two formats are compatible: you can send Smile and decode as JSON, by wrapping the proper decoder.* ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652452/fasterxml-jackson-smile-vs-json))

And even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile_%28data_interchange_format%29): *... which means that tools that operate on JSON may be used with Smile as well, as long as proper encoder/decoder exists for tool to use*

Unfortunately, I haven't find anything helpful in any of the sources except the information about encoder/decoder.

So the general question is **how can this be done**?

- Is there some built-in way for doing this?
- If not, are there some custom and already implemented solutions?
- If not, please, give me a few hints about writing encoder/decoder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class JsonSmileMigrationService
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonSmileMigrationService.class);

    public static byte[] convertToSmile(byte[] json, JsonFactory jsonFactory, SmileFactory smileFactory)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try // try-with-resources
        (
            JsonGenerator jg = smileFactory.createGenerator(bos);
            JsonParser jp = jsonFactory.createParser(json)
        )
        {
            while (jp.nextToken() != null)
            {
                jg.copyCurrentEvent(jp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Error while converting json to smile", e);
        }

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static byte[] convertToJson(byte[] smile, JsonFactory jsonFactory, SmileFactory smileFactory)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try // try-with-resources
        (
            JsonParser sp = smileFactory.createParser(smile);
            JsonGenerator jg = jsonFactory.createGenerator(bos)
        )
        {
            while (sp.nextToken() != null)
            {
                jg.copyCurrentEvent(sp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error("Error while converting smile to json", e);
        }

        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot assess how eficient this MO is, however, this simple straightforward way works fine: create a jackson mapper from SmileFactory, give it a JsonNode instance and have it map the input into a byte[] smile data:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();  // just for testing!
    ObjectMapper smileMapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());

    // create json test data
    SmileDemo sd = new SmileDemo();
    System.out.println("ORIGINAL " + sd.str + " " + sd.i + " " + sd.flt + " " + sd.dbl  + " " + sd.bool + " " + sd.date);
    JsonNode json = jsonMapper.valueToTree(sd);
    try {
        // the following line is the actual conversion
        byte[] smileData = smileMapper.writeValueAsBytes(json);
        // test the conversion
        sd = smileMapper.readValue(smileData, SmileDemo.class);
        System.out.println("CONVERTED " + sd.str + " " + sd.i + " " + sd.flt + " " + sd.dbl  + " " + sd.bool + " " + sd.date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class SmileDemo
{
    public String str = "Hello World";
    public int i = 1000;
    public float flt = 1000.34F;
    public double dbl = 1000.34D;
    public boolean bool = false;
    public java.util.Date date = new Date(2016, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify how it solves my problem? I don't see anything except serialization/deserialization to/from Smile... Let me shine some more light on my question: I have an array of bytes I got while serializing an object to Smile (`smileData` in your case). I want to convert this array of bytes to JSON string. Of course, the simplest solution would be deserializing it back and then serialize to JSON. Don't seem to be efficient...

Comment: you are right. This is indeed what is suggested and I do not have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

google found me this [class](https://github.com/kiha/jackson/blob/master/src/perf/TestJsonPerf.java) which contains a conversion from json byte array to smile one (do a search for `convertToSmile`). perhaps this helps?

Comment: +1 But actually it does unidirectional conversion. Post conversion in both sides and I will accept it as answer. Otherwise I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct transcoding, but relatively efficient way is to just read into `JsonNode` using format-specific mapper; write out using "the other" mapper. Like so:

```
final SmileMapper SMILE_MAPPER = new SmileMapper();
final JsonMapper JSON_MAPPER = new JsonMapper();

public byte[] smileBytesFromJson(byte[] json) throws IOException
{
  JsonNode tree = JSON_MAPPER.readTree(json);
  return SMILE_MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(tree);
}

public byte[] jsonBytesFromSmile(byte[] smile) throws IOException
{
  JsoNode tree = SMILE_MAPPER.readTree(smile);
  return JSON_MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(tree);
}
// can also take/produce String for JSON
```

But if the performance is REALLY important, you can alternative use `JsonParser`/`JsonGenerator` approach shown by the accepted answer; the idea is correct, create `SmileFactory`, `JsonFactory`, parser/generator pair, iterate over tokens, use `JsonGenerator.copyCurrentEvent(sourceParser);`